# Wacom Tablet not showing up on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, connection, wacom

I just bought a wacom intuos tablet, and when I plug it in, it doesn't show up in the System Settings. I have tried to run the code "xinput list" `xinput list`but it does not show up. It does show up with the code `lsusb | grep Wacom`, and with `lsmod | grep wacom`. I don't know where to go from here to fix it. It is working, but I can't make any setting changes without it showing up in the Settings.

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention which tablet you bought (output of lsusb), but most likely you need to update your kernel driver and your libwacom library. Follow the instructions at [1] for those two components.

[1] http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Downloads